# BizTalk Deployment 2016 through pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, biztalk, azure-pipelines, biztalk-2016, biztalk-deployment

I'm having trouble releasing my zip file that has been build onto my BizTalk server.

The specific problem occurs when i try to do a CreateApplication inside of the buildpipeline.

My pipeline consists of a Source control and 2 servers.

1. Push change to Git
2. BizTalk application gets build on buildserver and .ZIP togheter with bindingfiles inside gets exported to the deployment server (works perfectly as supposed)
3. Deploymentserver tries to start deployment but gets the below error.

Deployment Error 
[image: The property 'Version' cannot be found in this object. Verify that this property exists and can be set]

I have researched this but the only thing i can see is that on the test deployment server i don't have the "Version: property" compared to the actual production server whenever i look at the application Properties

Version missing on deployserver 
[image]

Version on other productionserver 
[image]

Important is that whenever I manually create the same application and run a "UpdateApplication" instead of a "CreateApplication" in my pipeline it seems to work. But this shouldn't mean that create shouldn't work. I need it to work since I need to redeploy because of how the project is build up.

All 3 featurepacks are installed with the latest CU's.

If anybody knows why the Version property isn't on any of my applications than please do let me know.

Comment: Within Your bindings file, can you ensure that the version property is well spelled?

Comment: Hi Hichamveo, Thanks ! Inside the binding file the application also has a version tag applied to it. It was empty by default. (Really weird because i did an export from BizTalk itself) After filling this in the pipeline works perfectly ! Thanks for your answer/comment.

Comment: @Siebe.V please close the question if that's all.